# How disable MQ error display when using exception hanling

Tags: console, ibm-mq

I am using java API to interact with MQ.
When I try to get a message from an empty queue, I get exception.
Ok, but when I control it with try catch, I am expecting not prompted any error message in console.
but I get!!

```
try {
    queue.get(getMessage, new MQGetMessageOptions());
    return getMessage.readUTF();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return "";
}
```

get in console as "MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'."
How can I disable this information output?
how can I check message availability or current queue size?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: How can I disable this information output? 
This link might help: [Hide Java Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894798/hide-java-output)

Second question: How can I check message availability or current queue size?

MQQueue.`getCurrentDepth`() method will get you the current queue size. But you must note that  this may not represent the correct queue depth at all times as messages could be consumed by other applications from the same queue. Actually you should not worry about queue depth. It is best practice to keep consuming messages and handle 2033 (MQJE001: MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) exception which is thrown when there are no messages in the queue in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method is using **MQException.log=null** line in your application.

Details bellow:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031000_.htm